# Fourier Transform in EmguCV 3.4.1

Tags: c#, emgucv

The following code doesn't compile in EmguCV 3.4.1.

```
        Image<Gray, float> image = new Image<Gray, float>(path);
        IntPtr complexImage = CvInvoke.cvCreateImage(image.Size, 
Emgu.CV.CvEnum.IplDepth.IplDepth32F, 2);

        CvInvoke.cvSetZero(complexImage);  // Initialize all elements to Zero
        CvInvoke.cvSetImageCOI(complexImage, 1);
        CvInvoke.cvCopy(image, complexImage, IntPtr.Zero);
        CvInvoke.cvSetImageCOI(complexImage, 0);

        Matrix<float> dft = new Matrix<float>(image.Rows, image.Cols, 2);
        CvInvoke.cvDFT(complexImage, dft, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DxtType.Forward, 0);

        //The Real part of the Fourier Transform
        Matrix<float> outReal = new Matrix<float>(image.Size);
        //The imaginary part of the Fourier Transform
        Matrix<float> outIm = new Matrix<float>(image.Size);
        CvInvoke.cvSplit(dft, outReal, outIm, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

        //Show The Data       
        CvInvoke.cvShowImage("Real", outReal);
        CvInvoke.cvShowImage("Imaginary ", outIm);
```

Some functions

```
cvSetZero()
cvDFT()
cvShowImage()
```

are not available in this version of EmguCV.

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Since version 3.0 EmguCV goes more for Mat instead of Image. Also somemethods were moved from CvInvoke to Mat or Image or were renamed (example: CvInvoke.cvShowImage --> CvInvoke.Imshow).

I also had this problem with dft and tried to port the code from the [openCV example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d8/d01/tutorial_discrete_fourier_transform.html) to c#. This is what I work with (using EmguCV 3.4.1):

```
    var image = new Mat(path, ImreadModes.Grayscale);

    int a = CvInvoke.GetOptimalDFTSize(image.Rows);
    int b = CvInvoke.GetOptimalDFTSize(image.Cols);

    var extended = new Mat();
    CvInvoke.CopyMakeBorder(image, extended, 0, a - image.Rows, 0, b - image.Cols, BorderType.Constant, new MCvScalar(0));

    extended.ConvertTo(extended, DepthType.Cv32F);
    var vec = new VectorOfMat(extended, new Mat(extended.Size, DepthType.Cv32F, 1));
    var complex = new Mat();
    CvInvoke.Merge(vec, complex);

    CvInvoke.Dft(complex, complex, DxtType.Forward, 0);

    CvInvoke.Split(complex, vec);

    vec[0].ConvertTo(vec[0], DepthType.Cv8U);
    vec[1].ConvertTo(vec[1], DepthType.Cv8U);

    CvInvoke.Imshow("Real", vec[0]);
    CvInvoke.Imshow("Img", vec[1]);
```

Comment: what is `VectorOfMat`?

Comment: VectorOfMat is a datastructure provided by EmguCV to hold multiple Mat objects. Some EmguCV methods need multiple Mat objects as input or output. In that case use VectorOfMat

Comment: Have you compared it to the output of the origninal sample you have posted? Use EmguCV version < 3.0 and run the original code. Btw, how dou you think the output should look like?

Comment: this is the photo of lena. you know how it should look like.

Answer (score 2):

Some methods have been renamed or moved. Use [`CvInvoke.Dft`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.1/document/html/030dfa0f-c105-c661-92d2-c79ba367df3b.htm) with [`Image.toUMat`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.1/document/html/a37add50-2e24-c3c4-5a22-3cea09b92157.htm) and [`UMat`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.1/document/html/8bb28349-1bcd-0876-a75e-693086e555e9.htm) for the image manipulation. [`ImageViewer`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.1/document/html/11133a18-edf5-95ac-79d7-97caef262dec.htm) can be used for displaying images.

```
Image<Gray, float> image = new Image<Gray, float>(path);
UMat dftImage = new UMat(image.Size, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F, 2);
CvInvoke.Dft(image, dftImage, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DxtType.Forward, image.Rows);
```

Comment: `/*Show The Data */  
            Image<Bgr, byte> im2 = dftImage.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
            pictureBox1.Image = im2.ToBitmap();` ........  this code is generating an exception.

Comment: What was the exception? Is this an `ImageBox` (http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.1/document/html/9276806f-79cf-fe8d-54d4-d7d896a96fef.htm)

Comment: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Emgu.CV.World.dll

Additional information: Unsupported conversion`