# 'System.Exception' occurred in Emgu.CV.World.dll

Tags: c#, emgucv

See: *[Fourier transform of an image in EmguCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7696910/159072)*
and, *[Fourier Transform in EmguCV 3.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51006195/159072)*

```
        Image<Gray, float> image = new Image<Gray, float>(path);
        UMat dftImage = new UMat(image.Size, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F, 2);
        CvInvoke.Dft(image, dftImage, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DxtType.Forward, image.Rows);          

        //Show The Data   
        Image<Bgr, byte> im2 = dftImage.ToImage<Bgr, byte>(); //exception is being raised here
        pictureBox1.Image = im2.ToBitmap();
```

The above code is generating the following exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in 
Emgu.CV.World.dll 
Additional information: Unsupported conversion
```

Also,     how can I show **real** and **imaginary** part of the image separately?

**Test Image:**

[image]

Comment: on which line are you getting this exception and what is the image format ?

Comment: @Prany, `Image<Bgr, byte> im2 = dftImage.ToImage<Bgr, byte>(); `.

Comment: And whats the image format as I tried with jpeg and found no issues

Comment: @Prany, `.jpg` and `.png`. Actually, none of them works.

Comment: Is that possible if you can attach the image here because it seems to be working my end . I am using Emgucv 3.1.0.1

Comment: @Prany, image added. I think image is okay. Probem is with something else.

Comment: @Prany, I am using EmguCV 3.4.1.

Comment: ahh got you, it is failing when trying with 3.4.1 - just got same error as yours.... try with 3.1.0.1